# Access IP camera using OpenCV in Python

Tags: python, opencv, ip-camera

I am trying to access my IP camera using OpenCV in Python, but when I run my code I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in cv::ipp_cvtColor, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 7456
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/taimur.islam/Desktop/ipcamera/b.py", line 11, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:7456: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::ipp_cvtColor

warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: http://Admin:Admin@192.168.10.74:8899/videostream.cgi?.mjpg (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://Admin:Admin@192.168.10.74:8899/videostream.cgi?.mjpg')

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It may be possible that you are getting delayed frames from `http://Admin:Admin@192.168.10.74`, or no frames at all, But you are not handling this scenario in your code, after `ret, frame = cap.read()`, you must check if a valid frame is received or not using `if ret==True:`. You may consult [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html) for more info

Comment: Just  change to while(cap.isOpened()):, and get the warning.                                                                                                             
warning: Error opening file (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:779)
warning: http://Admin:Admin@192.168.10.74:8899/videostream.cgi?.mjpg (/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:780)
again if ret==True: is tested, here no response means no frame is actually receiving

Comment: can you understand the reason of the error? i am stuck with this